# Shiny formula with variable names error

Tags: r, shiny

While trying to compute a formula with shiny i get an error. As a short example the reactivevalues is fed with an input button. Let´s say it contains a character vector (e.g Age). Adonis is available from the vegan library.

```
  values <-reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  adof <-  function()({

    #metadata is a dataframe with columns variables for each sample (Age,gender...)
    metadata <- as(sample_data(phyloseq), "data.frame")
    dis <- phyloseq::distance(phyloseq, method="uunifrac")
    #dis is a distance matrix 


    ad <- data.frame(adonis2(dis ~ values$data,data=metadata)
}
#Results
Error:object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

However if i use the following formula it will work. (changing reactivevalue with a character vector)

```
 adof <-  function()({

        metadata <- as(sample_data(phyloseq), "data.frame")
        dis <- phyloseq::distance(phyloseq, method="uunifrac")
        ad <- data.frame(adonis2(dis ~ Age ,data=metadata))           
        cat("Selected:"values$data)
        ad
        }

# Results
    selected: Age 
              Df  SumOfSqs        R2        F Pr..F.
    Age       4  9.863528 0.2394484 21.09395  0.001
    Residual 268 31.329187 0.7605516       NA     NA
    Total    272 41.192715 1.0000000       NA     NA
```

The way my reactive value is fed is with an observe statement

```
observe({ 
  # Fed reactive value with my selected radiobutton
  values$data =  input$data
})
```

Comment: is `dis` an reactive statement??

Comment: dis is inside  the adof function above.
 ``dis <- phyloseq::distance(phyloseq, method="uunifrac")``. 
Phyloseq is a phyloseq object from the phyloseq biocodncutor library.

Comment: what data are you using for the adonis2 function? I can only see that you are giving a formula.

Comment: I have update first post to include data and distance

Comment: what i don´t understand is why when use a variable like Age it works and when i Use values$data that contains Age as well it does not work ?

Comment: It is actually not very surprising Age is a variable whereas values$data is a string. Have you tried with something like `as.fomula(paste0("dis ~ ",values$data))`

Comment: @BertilBaron Thanks so much. It works !!!!

Comment: Ok I put it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `values$data` is variable containing a string. You have to convert it to a formula before you can use it.

try something like this.

```
adonis2(as.fomula(paste0("dis ~ ",values$data)),data=metadata)
```

Hope this helps!!